# Deleting entry with Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, restangular

I am using Restangular in my AngularJS app. I have a table with a delete link for each item. I would like to delete the item and have the row automatically removed. But as things are it only deletes from DB. How can I refactor things so that it the DOM is updated automatically?

```
// The controller
angular.module('myApp').controller('ManageCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {

  $scope.delete = function(e) {
     Restangular.one('product', e).remove();
  };

  Restangular.all('products').getList({}).then(function(data) {
    $scope.products = data.products;
    $scope.noOfPages = data.pages;
  });
});


 // The view
 <li ng-repeat="product in products">
   <a href="#" ng-click="delete(sheet._id)"></a>
  </li>
```

I would also love to find an example of this - even with Angular resource. All the admin/data table demos seem to work from static data.

Comment: Can you check in the code if item gets removed from `$scope.products` collection?

Comment: it doesn't. I'm thinking I have to delete from both the resource and the scope.products. I guess I am looking for a way to not have to do so - but there may not be.

Comment: You can always look at the restangular source and verify :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to Restangular https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#restangular-methods they mention that you should use the original item and run an action with it, so in your html code you should:

```
 <li ng-repeat="product in products">
   <a href="#" ng-click="delete(product)"></a>
</li>
```

Then in your controller:

```
 $scope.delete = function( product) {
    product.remove().then(function() {
      // edited: a better solution, suggested by Restangular themselves
      // since previously _.without() could leave you with an empty non-restangular array
      // see https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#removing-an-element-from-a-collection-keeping-the-collection-restangularized

      var index = $scope.products.indexOf(product);
      if (index > -1) $scope.products.splice(index, 1);
   });
 };
```

Notice they use the **underscore.js without** which will remove the element from the array. I guess that if they post that example in their readme page that means the `.remove()` function doesn't remove the original item from the collection. This makes sense, since not every item you remove you want removed from the collection itself.

Also, what happens if the `DELETE $HTTP` request fails? You don't want to remove the item then, and you have to make sure to handle that problem in your code.

Comment: Make sense. I don't have it working yet though. product.remove() calls the wrong url - not sure why - it does a DELETE /products instead of DELETE /products/ID

Comment: Ah solved!. I use Mongo so it sends _id instead of id. I need this config RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({ id: "_id" });

Comment: This totally works for me.  However if you remove the last element from $scope.products then it ceases to be a restangular project so you can not add items back into it.  I expected it to leave the core restangular stuff but it does not.  Any solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25786898/2634690 The solution there is to use splice on the `$.products` array

Comment: Or better yet - check out the solution by Restangular: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#removing-an-element-from-a-collection-keeping-the-collection-restangularized

Answer (score 2):

In my case the above didn't quite work. I had to do the following:

```
$scope.changes = Restangular.all('changes').getList().$object;

    $scope.destroy = function(change) {
        Restangular.one("changes", change._id).remove().then(function() {
            var index = $scope.changes.indexOf(change);
            if (index > -1) $scope.changes.splice(index, 1);
        });
    };
```